# Salutation formula - fallback not working in emails

Tags: formula, email-template, formula-field

I have a formular field with a simple formular in it (really? :) and it is used in various email templates.

```
If( ISPICKVAL(Salutation, "Mr."),"Sehr geehrter Herr " & LastName ,
If ( ISPICKVAL(Salutation, "Mrs."), "Sehr geehrte Frau " & LastName, "Guten Tag FirstName LastName,"
)
)
```

[image]

Basically it replaces the male or female salutation into a business one (which still works). If the contact didn´t specify it´s gender the fallback should work.

Which it did a few days back.
But now when I have a contact like this (it´s my testcontact) it looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Before it just replaced the variables. Now it displays the variables itself.

Anyone else have this and know who to bring back the fall back?

Kind regards
A.

Comment: Hi,
"Guten tag First name Last Name," is in quotes.
To replace First Name and Last Name
I think you need something like
"Guten tag" & First name & " " & Last name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that in your formula, if Salutation is neither `Mr.` nor `Mrs.` it would display `Guten Tag FirstName LastName`. It is expected that email template would show same `Guten Tag FirstName LastName`

Your formula should be corrected such that it concatenates FirstName and LastName fields to 'Guten Tag' string as below

```
If( ISPICKVAL(Salutation, "Mr."),"Sehr geehrter Herr " & LastName ,
If ( ISPICKVAL(Salutation, "Mrs."), "Sehr geehrte Frau " & LastName, "Guten Tag"& FirstName &LastName & ','
)
)
```

The issue with your formula was that you added firstname and lastname inside a string

Comment: Hi Swetha, thank you. So easy yet so far  ;) 
Now it works as expected.

Comment: Hi Swetha, I adjusted the last part so I have a space between each word:
If( ISPICKVAL(Salutation, "Mr."),"Sehr geehrter Herr " & LastName ,
If ( ISPICKVAL(Salutation, "Mrs."), "Sehr geehrte Frau " & LastName, "Guten Tag "&FirstName&" "&LastName&''
)
)
Thanks again